# How are wallets listed on bitcoin.org chosen?

Tags: blockchain.info

I only use coingate and blockchain.info and to my understanding, coingate is a party that handles transactions (make order, send and receive bitcoin) while blockchain.info is a wallet to store bitcoin. I have a few questions below:

1. Why can't coingate be a wallet itself?
2. In https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet, why blockchain.info is not listed? Was it not updated?

Comment: what do you mean by "bitcoin's party"?

Comment: @renlord Sorry I do not know the terms. What I mean of "bitcoin's party" is the organizations or people that related to bitcoin activities e.g. wallet provider or payment provider etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wallet listing is maintained based on best practices, as such wallets which are unsafe aren't listed. A discussion on Github removed blockchain.info from this listing, pending them making promised security upgrades. Specifically, the concerns raised by the maintainer included:

- Bugs and losses: BC.i has suffered from concerning issues during the past year (e.g. iOS denomination bug, weak key stretching, sizeable number of users losing funds, and more issues I haven't verified yet)
- Backup/Password Security: BC.i hasn't adopted security features which are slowly becoming standard in other wallets (e.g. BIP32, random passphrases, backup on setup, rotating addresses, 2FA by default).
- Transparency: Source code of the app has been reset or not updated repeatedly, making bitcoin.org often relay the false claim that the app is open-source.

Some of these are no longer the case, their new wallet does use BIP32 for example. The full discussion, where these points came from, along with detailed conversation with the developer are [available for review on github](https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/pull/663).

Comment: I feel that this is a very good history to learn from. But if they've followed the requirements strictly, it is acceptable to include them in the list at least? If not we will be switching from BC.I to another trusted provider. Just my opinion, thanks a lot.

Comment: @4LeaveCover That's a question for the people owning the bitcoin.org website.

Answer (score 2):

Coingate, Blockchain.info, and even Bitcoin.org are organizations that provide various Bitcoin-related services. They are not Bitcoin, itself. Which services/information these sites provide is their own business, and can change over time. The best place to get information on what these organizations provide is from the organizations themselves. Someone from Coingate may be able to tell you how to use it as a wallet, and someone from bitcoin.org can tell you why blockchain.info isn't listed. People here can guess...but it's best to go to the source.